# Textarea in IE8 Newline issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, textarea, newline

I'm making a cross-browser form, which requires a textarea.  This textarea receives data by two ways: 
- Sending an Ajax call to the server and returning data
- User inputted data

http://jsfiddle.net/garrettwong/x3KSP/

I'm having an issue on IE8 where the textarea text is not formatted (newlines not being read), where as in Chrome, the same code, nicely formats the textarea.  I'm hoping to use a solely JavaScript solution if possible, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why are you using `text()`? Set the value using [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

New lines are normally `\n\r`.

Comment: This did the trick.  Replacing with \n\r and using val() instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Do a replace operation to  ensure that there is a `\r` before every `\n`:

```
str = str.replace(/\r?\n/g, "\r\n");
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/x3KSP/8/)

Browsers use `\r\n` for line breaks, though modern browsers such as Chrome and Firefox can also handle Unix-style `\n` line breaks. IE8 requires proper `\r\n` line breaks, which work in all other browsers as well.

And as @epascarello noted, use `.val()` to manipulate the textarea's `value` property.

Answer (score 2):

Just use "\r\n" for new lines.

Comment: This appends double linefeeds, why not `\r\n`?