# New line character "\n" not supported in IE 8 browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have use the below HTML code snippet to display text, but unable to do so in Internet Explorer 8 version.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head>
       <title></title>
          <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
          <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
       <div>
         <pre id="test">
         </pre>
      </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#test").html("WELCOME\nHello World")
    });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

This code snippet works fine as expected in IE's latest versions but “**\n**” is not working in  IE8 version . How to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: \r\n is the windows (and thus IE) line break

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10889963/3538503

Comment: Try replacing `"\n"` with `"\r\n"`. As far as I know, this comes from a long time ago when `\n` meant "next line", and `\r` meant "line return" or "move the cursor all the way too the left of the screen". For whatever, most Microsoft products still need the full `"\r\n"`.

Comment: I dont think its work in other browser to... beacause you append html in div and `\n` not work as html you should use `<br>`

Comment: @AnantDabhi, missed you `pre` element?

Comment: @vp_arth Yeah you are right so , @edwin should use `\r\n`  :)

Comment: And I think, this is not best practice to use `\r\n` anywhere, if you use UNIX `\n` in your source files as linefeed. `IE` can to accept `\n` correctly, if you understand how `IE` with DOM works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try more correct DOM manipulation:

```
document.getElementById("test")
    .appendChild(document.createTextNode("WELCOME\nhelloworld"));
```

It should work.

**Also**, you can use `outerHTML` to force render in IE:

```
var el = document.getElementById("test")
if (el.tagName == "PRE" && "outerHTML" in el) { // check `outerHTML` exists (it's not in Firefox)
    var outer = el.outerHTML;
    var preservedAttrs = outer.substring(0, outer.indexOf('>') + 1);
    el.outerHTML = preservedAttrs + str + "</PRE>";
}
else {
    el.innerHTML = str;
}
```

**Another** way is to use `nodeValue` to preserve text from IE preprocessing:

```
document.getElementById('test').firstChild.nodeValue = "WELCOME\nhelloworld";
```

Answer (score 1):

To ensure compatibility with IE 8 try to use \r\n instead of just \n

Answer (score 1):

In all cases, you should replace the `\n` with `<br/>` since you are submitting HTML, not text.  The `\n` should have had issues in all browsers.

Comment: Ahhh ... missed that.  Then the \r\n would be correct.

Comment: if we want to get "better", i would go <p> over <br> if possible; <pre> is weak sauce

Answer (score -1):

`\r\n` is the windows linebreak. `\n` works for linux.

Having said that, `\r\n` will not work if you intend to use it to break text to another line in the rendered HTML page. For that you should use `<br/>`.